# creating and exporting a csv from JSP

Tags: jsp, csv, export

I have created a report which will export the data to the xls and when I set the contentType and Header to the suggested types.. It  just fills the entire code in the csv file( including html tags ). Any help on this is really appreciated.

```
<%@page import="org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext" %>
<%@ page contentType="application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<% response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=\"DownloadReport.csv\""); %>
```

Regards,
Senny

Answer (score 0):

You need to save and call it with `.jsp` extension in order to get JSP code to run. Do not save and call it with `.csv` extension or something which represents plain text.

Comment: I have saved it as .jsp.. The problem is when I click on the csv link which calls the above jsp.. it gives me a csv file, but the problem is.. it has the entire jsp code in there..